# Ag-grid Sort column data and then "Release" sorting

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using enterprise AG-Grid in Angular 8 and using the "Unmanaged Dragging" feature. I am trying to sort the data and then only drag and drop some of the sorted rows but the grid gets locked once the sorting is applied. Is there a way to sort the data and then release the sort so that the data is sorted but not locked.
I looked at the documentation but it has options to "reset" the sorting which basically puts the data in its previous state which is not helpful.
Tried this.gridColumnApi.applyColumnState({ defaultState: { sort: null } }); which is not helpful. Can anyone help?